# How to begin to practice vipassana meditation?

Tags: meditation, vipassana, meditation-practicalities, meditation-insight, meditation-recommendation

I've been practicing meditation and studying buddhism for years, and I've always been curious about *vipassana*, but I never knew how should I practice it, on what should I focus, etc.

So my questions is: what do you recommend for someone who is starting *vipassana* meditation? How do I begin and how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic insight meditation (*[vipassana](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/vipassana-meditation/)*) based on the mindfulness of breathing, you can consider starting with [Ven. Yuttadhammo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuttadhammo_Bhikkhu)'s "[How To Meditate](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/)" series for beginners, which is available as a [YouTube video playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL603BD0B03E12F5A1) and as an [online book](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/).

This meditation is based on the four foundations of mindfulness (*[satipatthana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satipatthana)*). It comes in the varieties of sitting and walking meditation.

After you have mastered this, you can proceed to "[How to Meditate II](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate-ii/)" by the same teacher.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this source useful:
https://www.dhamma.org/en-US/index

Whichever you go for, make sure they are reliable meditation coming from genuine sources and not merely anyone claiming to be teaching or talking about vipassana.